# PHAsset location metadata iCloud synchronization

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I have an iCloud database across several iOS and macOS devices and when i update the `location` of a `PHAsset` it does not propagate to other devices even though they appear to be in sync. The location appears in the local device photo library but not on other devices. My understanding is that this metadata is supposed to sync. No?

Code:

```
func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    guard let asset = asset else { return }

    willChangeValue(forKey: "coordinate")

    coordinate = newCoordinate

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: asset)
        request.location = CLLocation(latitude: self.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.coordinate.longitude)
    }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
        self.didChangeValue(forKey: "coordinate")
    })
}
```